# Why does commit in my previous pull request still appears in the next one?

Tags: git, github

I'm newbie to git so this may sounds stupid but my situation is:

- Forked
- Modified, push to my fork master
- Pulled and got my pull request accepted & merged

Then after sometime, I did:

- Pulled updates from original master to fork (git pull http://master-url master)
- Modified & push to to my fork master (git push origin master)
- Pulled (created pull request)
- Here I see previous commit in the pull while it was already merged ????

What should I do here ?

Comment: Your question doesn't sound stupid, but it is confusing.  Can you us a diagram of commits for the branch in question?

Comment: Please show the exact commands used for each step. You can use dummy file and branch names, but we need more detail to understand what you are doing. For steps involving GitHub, be more specific about what you clicked.

Comment: I've added some extra explanation by commands I used, I'm not really sure how to show the diagram.

Comment: @bigopon Have your previous/first pull req already merged with your upstream (from where you forked)?

Comment: @sajibkhan Yeah it was.

Comment: Tks, I rebased remote && push -f and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly First pull request is merged after creating the Second pull request.

```
First pull request (master): A -- B  
Second pull request (master): A -- B -- C -- D
```

- Normally pull request is created on a branch (with all commits exists in that branch)
- As you are creating your second pull request from your master, `commits A & B` also available here so, you can see your previous commits.

Comment: From what you said, what should I do ? Delete my old fork and make a new one ?

Comment: You can update your `fork master` with `upstream master`, make sure commit A & B is available in `fork master`. Then do your changes (commit C & D) in your fork master. Now create pull request again.

Comment: The second pull was created after the first was merged.

What is the right command to do when the `upstream master` hasn't been released yet ? Actually my real question would be where do I find the real link to `upstream master` ?